# Using a list across multiple types in C#

Tags: c#

I am working on a utility class in a C# app. Either I'm rusty or something is configured incorrectly. I want to have a class that accepts a list of any type of object. In an effort to do this, I wrote the following:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace MyProject
{
    public class ItemCollection
    {
        public List<object> Items { get; set; }

        public ItemCollection(List<Object> items)
        {
            Items.Clear();
            foreach (Object item in items)
            {
              Items.Add(item);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I then call this code using:

```
var myItem = new MyItem();
var myItems= new List<MyItem>();
myItems.Add(myItem);

var result = new MyCollection(myItems);
```

This gives me a compile-time error that says:

```
cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List<MyProject.MyItem>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<object>'
```

I thought everything derived from `object`. So, shouldn't this work?

Either way, I thought generics would be more appropriate. I tried using the following:

```
public List<T> Items{ get; set; }
```

Yet, that gives me a compile-time error that says:

```
The type or namespace name 'T' could not be found
```

That seems incorrect to me. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: why are you calling Items.Clear in the constructor ? it's not just redundant it will also throw NullReferenceException.

Comment: related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5881677/why-cant-i-cast-from-a-listmyclass-to-listobject

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add a type parameter to your entire class:

```
public class ItemCollection<T>
{
    public List<T> Items { get; set; }

    public ItemCollection(List<T> items)
    {
        Items.Clear();
        foreach (T item in items)
        {
          Items.Add(item);
        }
    }
}
```

On an unrelated note, you can simplify your constructor to

```
Items = new List<T>(items);
```