# cannot implicitly convert type system.collections.generic.list

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

In advance I apologize if I’m asking something obvious. I’m switching from regular asp.net programming to MVC and from vb to c#. It been fine but I still have much to learn.

I'm getting the following error

> Cannot implicitly convert type system.collections.generic.list <project.models.state> to system.collections.generic.list<project.state>. an implicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

this is what I have in my controller

```
 public ActionResult CityForm()
    {

        var states= _context.Departamentos.ToList();
        var viewModel = new CityFormViewModel
        {
            City= new City(),
            States= states
        };
        return View();
    }
```

My viewModel looks as follows

```
  public IEnumerable<State> States{ get; set; }

  public City City{ get; set; }
```

I have looked into other post that have a similar error, but it seems the cause is something different to what I have. I have used this approach before in a different application and it worked fine, what I've done different in this one is that I added a ADO.NET Entity Data Model, to use with Telerik controls.

I've also noticed that in my other application when I hover the variable in my controller I get the following message (between ** is what I'm hovering the mouse over):

```
States = **states**
(local variable)List<State> states
```

but if I hover in the same place in the application where I get the error I get a different message

```
States = **states**
(local variable)List<Models.State> states
```

as you can see is prefixing State with Models.

I really appreciate any help I can get. Thanks.

Comment: `project.models.state` is not `project.state` (they are in different assemblies). Your view model property needs to be `public IEnumerable<Project.Models.State> States { get; set; }` - the same as your query returns (and stop using `var`!)

Comment: I don't see any problem in how he is using var. He would have gotten the same compiler error if he had not use var. Because he is using var he has to fix less code.

Comment: @bit2know I think the problem with `var` is obvious in this case: it makes it more difficult to see type mismatches.

Comment: So far question is roughly "why different types are different"... and the answer "because they are different" which is not exactly clear... Some clarification why you expect silent conversion between "project.models.state" and "project.state" (which at least somewhat would explain why you expect two lists be compatible - also you probably know that they can't be - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5881677/why-cant-i-cast-from-a-listmyclass-to-listobject)

Comment: @BJMyers maybe. When doing implicit casts it can be good to be verbose about what types you are using.  But I don't think getting rid of var would have prevented this problem. The compilation error message does way more, as far as, helping him to fix it. Sooner or later he's going to get past little mistakes like that and should not be scared off of using `var`. The second var is perfectly fine. Specifying a variable type when using `new` is entirely redundant .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have the same Class name from different location. if you want to assign the value, do mind they need to be on the same type.

in your case, you have to choose either `IEnumerable<project.state>` or `IEnumerable<project.models.state>` only not to assign `project.state` to `project.models.state`

Comment: Awesome that did it, I really appreciate your help. I

Comment: glad i could help